# Catching process stdout from another python script

Tags: python, linux, windows, cmd, process

I have launched popen task
'''
p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-', '-oX', '192.168.19.159'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
'''

In cmd tasklist command i can see pid of the laucnhed process ([image])

Can i create new python script, from which i can connect to my launched process by pid and get stdout from launched process?

I tried libraries psutil,subprocess. But i did not find answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

It tells that the returned object of `Popen` provides `stdout` and  `stderr` as fields for the captured output. You should be able to iterate over those lines.

Comment: can i get the stdout variable in another py file?

Comment: It's not clear how you intend to use it. A python file that does create a process can capture its output as mentioned. What do you want to do with another python file?